# How to draw a triangular portion of a bitmap

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to draw a triangular portion of a bitmap. I already know how to draw a filled triangle using path, and I already know that the answer may involve something called BitmapShader, but I can not find any clear documentation or examples to put it all together.

**EDIT:** After much flailing and experimentation, I am now nearly there. My code looks like this:

```
Paint paint;
Path path = new Path();
BitmapShader bms = new BitmapShader(shrub_bitmap,TileMode.REPEAT ,TileMode.REPEAT  );
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
paint.setShader(bms);
path.reset();
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
path.moveTo(x1,y1);
path.lineTo(x2,y2);
path.lineTo(x3,y3);
path.close();
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
paint.setShader(null);
```

The only remaining problem is that the bitmap from which the triangle is drawn is rooted to the screen coordinates. This means that when the triangle is being animated (i.e. being drawn at various points around the screen), it has the appearance of being a window allowing us to see a static image underneath. What I actually want is for the bitmap to be tied to the triangle so that the triangle looks like a solid object moving around. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your second question:

try using canvas.translate(x1, y1) and moveTo(0, 0), lineTo(x2 - x1, y2 - y1) ...

Comment: I was very confused that canvas.translate(0, 0) does not undo the translation!.. I need canvas.translate(-x1, -y1); .. but all working now.

Comment: you can also use canvas.save() canvas.translate(x, y).... and canvas.restore()
the restore reestablishes the transformation state before the last save.